# Automatic shutoff circuit without a switch

Tags: power, mosfet

Looking at the simple automatic shutoff circuit from [here](https://www.edn.com/simple-automatic-shutoff-circuit-uses-few-components/)

[image]

I was wondering if it is possible to modify this circuit so that instead of using a push switch, the circuit will just power off (say 250ms).

My circuit is low-side switched, so everything is at 48V until the parent circuit provides a path to ground. Most of the time these pulse events are 50ms or so, but sometimes things go wrong and I want this sub circuit to pinch off the flow of current after 250 ms or so to save the load from burning up. Like a fast resettable slow-blow fuse.

Comment: The problem of such circuits is, that for a significant amount of time during the slow decay of the gate voltage Vgs the MOSFET is neither fully conducting nor completely turned off. In this phase the FET dissipates a lot of heat and may fail. What is the maximum load current?

Comment: Yeah that was a thought. 11 amps. Could drive it with a bjt to make that off transition steep?

Comment: You need some kind of comparator or TL431 circuit with additional hysteresis, a BJT with the large base current is not a great improvement.